# ms Access Vb Hanging and not generating the mail

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Please help below code is not generating the mail and hangs access application:

Where is issue as when I dont do dQuery Processing Email Generates properly but dont include subform records aswell.

Without Subform Details Mail is something like this [Email Generated with Proper variables present on MainForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbr8h.png)

```
Private Sub InformCustomer_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_InformCustomer_Click

Dim CustName As String      ' Customer Name
Dim varTo As Variant        '-- Address for SendObject
Dim stText As String        '-- E-mail text
Dim DelDate As Variant      '-- Rec date for e-mail text
Dim stSubject As String     '-- Subject line of e-mail
Dim stOrderID As String     '-- The Order ID from form
Dim strSQL As String        '-- Create SQL update statement
Dim errLoop As Error

Dim dQuery As String
Dim MyDb As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

stOrderID = Me![OdrID]

strSQL = "SELECT BrandName, ModelName, Status " _
& " FROM OrderProdDetails " _
& " WHERE (OrdID)=" & stOrderID & ";"
Set MyDb = CurrentDb
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
While Not rs.EOF
dQuery = dQuery & rs![BrandName].Value & vbTab & rs![ModelName].Value & rs![Status].Value & vbCrLf     
Wend
Set rs = Nothing

CustName = Me![CustName]

varTo = Me![CustEmail]

stSubject = ":: Update - Oder Status ::"

stOrderID = Me![OdrID]
DelDate = Me![OdrDeliveryDate]

stText = "Dear" & CustName & Chr$(13) & _
         "You have been assigned a new ticket." & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
         "Order Number: " & stOrderID & Chr$(13) & _
          _
         "Please refer to your order status " & Chr$(13) & _
         "Exp Delevery Date: " & DelDate & Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) & _
          dQuery & Chr$(13) & _
         "This is an automated message. Please do not respond to this e-mail."

'Write the e-mail content for sending to assignee
DoCmd.SendObject , , acFormatTXT, varTo, , , stSubject, stText, True

MsgBox "Done"

Exit Sub

Err_InformCustomer_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an endless loop.

```vb
While Not rs.EOF
    dQuery = dQuery & rs![BrandName].Value & vbTab & rs![ModelName].Value & rs![Status].Value & vbCrLf 
    ' This is missing -->
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks Andre,

You Saved me :)

Comment: @SK: This will help you in the future to find bugs like that yourself: [How to debug your VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)